# Gateway not being remembered

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

Every time I reboot my SBS 2008 server I have to manually enter in the gateway. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried re-running the "Connect to the Internet" wizard?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your issue is documented in [KB973243](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;973243). Download the hotfix that is listed in that article. You will also need to navigate to this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Para 
meters\Interfaces\<Your NIC's GUID>\DefaultGateway` and get rid of blank lines that exist. You may want to just delete all values and re-type your default gateway IP address making sure that no blank characters exist.

In summary:

1. Install Hotfix
2. Remove blanks from the registry key
3. Reboot